# Checking for a null pointer fails

Tags: c++

Disclosure, this is for a homework assignment.

I'm working on a hash table very similar to the one found here: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Simple_example

When I get to inserting an element into the table, there is a check to make sure the current array element is not null as seen below:

```
    while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->status != DELETED)
    hash = (hash + 1) % tablesize;
```

For whatever reason, this doesn't seem to protect the pointer, as the program crashes.  The debugger shows the following for table:

```
-       table   0x004892d8 {0xcdcdcdcd {status=??? key=??? e={...} }}   HashElement<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > > * *
```

I have no idea what any of that means :|

Comment: `0xcdcdcdcd` pattern is the debugger's way of saying "this object has already been destroyed". Figure out where and how `table` became a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks.  There really isn't much going on in the program so far.  The class is defined as:  http://ideone.com/TtsPpq   The insert() method is essentially what I posted before.  Is the HashTable() constructor not properly instantiating the table?

Comment: Maybe the pointer is deleted, but not set to NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm new to C++ so its just going to take a little getting used to.

Comment: Being new to C++ i'd recommend you to not use `new` (ironically). Building a hashtable can be done quite fine by building on the standard library containers.

Comment: `table` points to an array of `HashTable*` pointers. That array has not been initialized, and contains random garbage. None of the elements are `NULL` (except perhaps by accident).